# How can I write a JavaScript function that will call another function passed as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, math

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that will integrate functions using Simpson's Rule. I fully understand the math behind Simpson's Rule, but I'm unsure of how to write a function that will integrate another function. Here's the code I'd like to implement:

```
integrate = function(leftBound, rightBound, numSubIntervals, expression) {

    var a = leftBound,
        b = rightBound,
        n = numSubIntervals,
        myFunc = expression;

    /*implementation of simpson's rule..*/

    return result;
}
```

My issue is that I don't know how to pass a mathematical expression (the function to be integrated) as a parameter without doing something like passing it as a string and using eval(), which is not something I want to do. I also don't want to use any third-party libraries. I want to write the function using vanilla JavaScript only. What am I missing here - is there an obvious solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible.... You can pass a function as a parameter without any issues `var myFunc = function(x){ return x+1; }; integrate(..,..,.., myFunc)` and then call it through `expression(x_value)`

Comment: this is not pseudocode. It's code with a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions themselves can be arguments to other functions. For example:

```
integrate(0,5,10, function(x){
 return x*x;
})
```

This example takes a function that takes a given X and squares it. Within `integrate`, you would call this function for given intervals of x to integrate this function using Simpson's rule.

---

Within `integrate`, the syntax for calling a function passed to it is:

```
var point = expression(x);
```

Where `x` is the value passed to the function named `expression`, and `point` is the return value of `expression`.

Comment: okay, but how would I refer to the anonymous function within the function called 'integrate'?

Comment: I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help Peter -  that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer-version of my comment. You can pass the function as parameter and then call it from inside.

```
integrate = function(leftBound, rightBound, numSubIntervals, expression) {

    var a = leftBound,
        b = rightBound,
        n = numSubIntervals,
        myFunc = expression;

    /*implementation of simpson's rule..*/
    result = (b-a)/6 * (expression(a) + 4*f* ... );

    return result;
}

var toIntegrate = function(x){
  return 2*x*x*x - 3*x*x + 2*x - 1;
}

integrate(0, 10, 10, toIntegrate);
```

Comment: thanks for actually offering help, @olivarra1, instead of just correcting my styling, etc. I wonder, though, is there any way to have only one code block, instead of also having to declare the 'toIntegrate' function separately?